# new 10GBE network card not connecting

Tags: networking, fedora, network-interface, networkmanager

I recently installed a new 10gbe network card in my fedora34 machine. it shows up correctly but it fails establishing a connection. I tried a different cable & port on the switch (that work with a different device) so the problem is most likely with my machine.

ifconfig:

```
enp37s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 80:61:5f:0c:72:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 129  bytes 17375 (16.9 KiB)
        RX errors 9  dropped 39  overruns 0  frame 9
        TX packets 1473  bytes 235023 (229.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

nmcli dev status

```
DEVICE   TYPE       STATE                   CONNECTION
enp37s0  ethernet   unavailable             --
```

ncmli con

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE
Wired connection 2  e3056570-ccd2-35d3-9d71-70fb91568d4a  ethernet   --
```

and `dmesg` contains tons of log lines like this:

```
[77823.422096] ixgbe 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
[77823.422780] ixgbe 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: NIC Link is Down
[78353.098269] ixgbe 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
[78353.202105] ixgbe 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: NIC Link is Down
```

ethtool enp37s0

```
ethtool  enp37s0
[sudo] password for clemens:
Settings for enp37s0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: Direct Attach Copper
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no
```

lspci -vv

```
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 10 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Device 1dcf:0317
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 30
        IOMMU group: 14
        Region 0: Memory at f0300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Region 2: I/O ports at d000 [size=32]
        Region 4: Memory at f0380000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at fc500000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
        Kernel modules: ixgbe
```

nmcli logs

```
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2105] device (enp37s0): carrier: link connected
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2110] device (enp37s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2181] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 2' (e3056570-ccd2-35d3-9d71-70fb91568d4a)
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2186] device (enp37s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (e3056570-ccd2-35d3-9d71-70fb91568d4a)
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2187] device (enp37s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2192] device (enp37s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2281] device (enp37s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 11 17:07:05 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724025.2284] dhcp4 (enp37s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 11 17:07:12 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724032.2762] device (enp37s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 11 17:07:12 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724032.2919] dhcp4 (enp37s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 11 17:07:12 fedora NetworkManager[958]: <info>  [1620724032.2920] dhcp4 (enp37s0): state changed unknown -> terminated
```

(repeats over and over)
the router receives the DHCP request and assigns an IP address, I couldn't find any other logs on the router's side and no errors/warnings there (running openwrt)

so far google has not been able to find anything regarding this particular issue. How can I enable debug logs or find logging that can tell me why exactly the connection cannot be established?

Comment: I found out how to enable debug logs:
https://pastebin.com/LP5wedqy

Comment: Would it be possible for you to try it with plain Linux without the overcomplicated network manager? Just `ip` from `iproute2` package setting the adddress and then setting the interface up? Messages from driver would be in `dmesg`.

Comment: isn't the ip supposed to be assigned via DHCP?

Comment: on my router I can see that the router reserves an ip address for the device, but the machine never gets to use it somehow. so some communication between the machine and the router is possible, it just doesn't manage to establish the connection all the way ...

Comment: Well, it's always usefull to split a problem to pieces. And in this case I would go from the down up (according to ISO OSI model). So first you need to know if the physical connection is all right. You can check the transciever via eth-tool. But it might be a bit difficult. So remembering this was skipped, then the next step would be to let the link up and down and see what driver says. DHCP can be excercised with more detail using e. g. `dhclient` later.

Comment: I tried setting an ip address and the machine stopped responding :(

Comment: And wasn't it just that you were remote connected to a different address? If not, and the kernel wasn't able to utter a word to dmesg and collapsed, than it's kind of seriously broken. Did you use a local console? Which command exactlly you performed?

Comment: I was remotely connected to it using a different network card/connection. I did  ip addr add 192.168.1.119/24 dev enp37s0 which probably killed my connection and made the machine unreachable. not sure why adding an ip to one device disrupts the connection on another device?

Comment: Sounds wierd. I am not familiar enough with the ever-changing NM, on plain Linux/Unix setup this should never happen.